How to study the cross-correlation distribution of the set of sequences consisting of both $m$-sequences and quadratic sequences?
Let $f(m):\mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+}_{even}$ is a function from the set of positive integer to the set positive even integer. Then by the $[f(m)-1]$-BCH code I mean the BCH code with designed distance $f(m)-1$ and code length $2^m - 1$. Whereas $[f(m)]$-BCH code denote the even parity sub-code the $[f(m)-1]$-BCH code, i.e. $[f(m)]$-BCH code is consists of all the even parity code vectors of a given $[f(m)-1]$-BCH code. Let $a_j$ denote the number of code-vectors of weight $j$ in a given linear code. Now,the next theorem is from T.Kasami's work
$\textbf{Theorem 1:}$  For an odd integer $ m\geq 3$, define
$$
  w_1= 2^{m -1} - 2^{(m + 1)/2 -1},\ 
  w_2= 2^{m - 1},
  w_3 = 2^{m - 1} + 2^{(m + 1)/2 - 1}. 
  $$
Then, a $[2^{m-1}- 2^{(m-1)/2}]$-BCH code
has the following distribution:
\begin{align*}
   &  a_0 =1,\\
   &  a_{w_1} = 
   (2^{m - 2} + 2^{(m - 1)/2 -1}) (2^{m} - 1),\\
   &  a_{w_2}  = (2^{m}- 2^{m - 1 } + 1) (2^{m} - 1),\\
   & a_{w_3}  = 
   (2^{m - 2} - 2^{(m - 1)/2 -1}) (2^{m} - 1),\\
   &  a_j = 0,\ \mbox{for other values of $j$.}
  \end{align*}
Let $\mathcal{H}:=\{\mathbf{b}_1 , \mathbf{b}_2 ,..., \mathbf{b}_{a_{w_2}}\}$ denote the set of all the code-vectors of weight $w_2$ in above given BCH code. Define the matrix $B$ as
$$B = \big[\mathbf{b}_1 \big| \mathbf{b}_2 \big|\cdot \cdot \cdot \big|\mathbf{b}_{a_{w_2}}\big].$$
Define $ o:= 2^{m -2} + 2^{(m + 1)/2 -2},\ p:= 2^{m - 2},\ q:= 2^{m -2} - 2^{(m + 1)/2 -2}.$ As a consequence of $\textbf{Theorem 1}$, it can be easily shown that for $i \neq j$, $\langle \mathbf{b}_j, \mathbf{b}_i \rangle \in \{o, p,q\}$, where $\langle , \rangle$ is the euclidian inner product (where the multiplication and addition is defined over $\mathbb{R}$).  Let $j\in [a_{w_2}]$ be arbitrary. Define the multiset (multisets are the set that allow repetetion) $S$ as
$$S:= \{\langle \mathbf{b}_j, \mathbf{b}_i \rangle : \forall i \in [a_{w_2}]\setminus \{j\} \}.$$
Now, I know that the multiset $S$ contains only the values $o,p,q$, albeit with repetetions. Now, I need to find the number of times each of the values $o,p,q$ occurred in $S$. In other words I need to count the frequencies of each of values $o,p,q$ in the multiset $S$. At first, I thought that this would be an easier task because I was under the impression that the set $\mathcal{H}$ is consist of circular shifts of $2^{m-1}+1$ unique $m$-sequences of period $2^{m}-1$. However, it was not the case. for example, a $2$-BCH code of length $7$ has the following weight distribution:
$$a_0 := 1$$
$$a_2 := 21$$
$$a_4 := 35$$
$$a_6:= 7.$$
Let $\mathcal{H}:= \{\mathbf{b}_1 , \mathbf{b}_2 ,...,\mathbf{b}_{35}\}$ denote the set of all the code-vectors of weight $4$.
Using the simulation, I found that the set  $\mathcal{H}$ is consist of different circular shifts of the following five sequences:
$$c_1:= [1,0,0,0,1,1,1]^{T},\ c_2:= [0,1,1,1,0,0,1]^{T},\ c_3:= [1,1,1,0,1,0,0]^{T},$$
$$c_4:= [1,1,0,0,1,1,0]^{T},\ 
c_5:= [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]^{T}.$$
As pointed out by the user kodlu, for the sequence of length $7$ there are only two unique $m$-sequence. So, out of the five sequences that I have found, there are only two unique $m$-sequences and the remaining are quadratic sequences. And, in order to mathematically find the frequencies of $o,p,q$ in $S$, I need to find the cross-correlation distribution of set of sequences containing bot $m$-sequences and quadratic sequences. I contrast to $m$-sequences, there are almost no literature available on cross-correlation of quadratic sequences.
**So, can somebody shed some light on how  I can obtain the mathematical expression for the frequencies of the values $o,p,q$ in the multiset $S$ **.

What is your definition of an $m$-sequence, and how does it compare with that of Zierler who introduced the term? For most people, an $m$-sequence of period $2^m-1$ is generated by a linear feedback shift register with $m$ stages.

@DilipSarwate ; I am sorry! I am new to coding theory. I was under the impression that a periodic sequence of length $2^{m}-1$ with $2^{m-1}$ number of ones, with period $2^{m}-1$ is a maximal length sequence. Nevertheless, I need to study the cross-correlation distribution between those five $c_i$ sequences given in my question. Is there a way to study them?

Have you looked at the chapter on sequences in The Handbook of Coding Theory? Authored by Vijay Kumar and Tor Helleseth IIRC.

To study cross-correlation of sequences in the small Kasami code you absolutely need to move from $\Bbb{F}_2$ to real numbers, and start summing up $\pm1$s. If you insist on thinking of $0$ and $1$ as real numbers, a random sequence will average out somewhere close to $0.5$, and to get correlation you need to subtract anyway.
Conveniently, characters of finite field do exactly that by adding that extra layer, mapping the elements of $\Bbb{F}_2$ to real numbers $\{\pm1\}$ using the formula $x\mapsto (-1)^x$.  Observe that this is well-defined in the sense that here $x$ is a coset in $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, but any two integers $x,x'$ in the same coset share the same parity, and consequently also the same value of $(-1)^x=(-1)^{x'}$.
Combining this with the trace function from Kodlu's answer you get what are known as additive characters of finite field $GF(2^n)=\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$. Those are group homomorphisms $\chi:(\Bbb{F}_{2^n},+)\to (\Bbb{C}^*,\cdot)$, In other words, we require that
$$\chi(x+y)=\chi(x)\cdot\chi(y)$$
for all $x,y\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$. We get one such (I am fond of calling it the canonical additive character, but that term is not in universal use. It is defined
as
$$e:\Bbb{F}_{2^n}\to\Bbb{C}^*, x\mapsto (-1)^{tr(x)}.$$
I call it "canonical" because in addition to the character property $e(x+y)=e(x)e(y)$ it also satisfies the identity $e(x)=e(x^2)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$. And (in characteristic two) it is the only non-constant additive character satisfying this extra condition. Furthermore, it is not difficult to prove that all the additive characters of $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ have the form
$$
\chi=\chi_a:x\mapsto e(ax),
$$
where $a\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ can be chosen freely. The choice $a=0$ gives the constant character, and the choice $a=1$ the canonical character.
An important property of characters is the so called orthogonality
$$
\langle \chi_a,\chi_b\rangle:=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}}\chi_a(x)\chi_b(x)=
\begin{cases}2^n,&\text{if $a=b$}\\ 0,&\text{if $a\neq b$.}\end{cases}
$$

A recurring tool is that by converting a sequence of bits like $c=(1,0,0,1,0,1,1)$
into $\pm1$s as above $c\mapsto s=(-1,+1,+1,-1,+1,-1,-1)$ we can calculate the Hamming weight $w$ of $c$ from the sum
$$S(s)=\sum_{i=0}^6 s(i)=4\cdot(-1)+3\cdot1=7\cdot1-2\cdot4=7-2w.$$
More generally, $7$ should be replaced by the length of the sequence. The reason why this shows up is that many codes (such as the small Kasami code) have words gotten by evaluating the trace of a polynomial at all the points of a finite field $F=GF(2^n)$. Often zero is left out. You see that in both cases we get the weight of a codeword from a character sum.

Undoubtedly you know that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic (or order $2^n-1$). If $g$ is a generator of , we get ($\pm1$-valued) $m$-sequences by the recipe
$$s_a(j)=\chi_a(g^j), \quad j=0,1,\ldots, 2^m-2, a\in F^*.$$
In other words, the order of the components matches the cyclic order of elements of $F^*$. As $g^{2^n-1}=1$ it also follows that the above rule (if extended) would give a periodic sequence of period $2^n-1$.
Example.If $g\in GF(8)$ is a root of the primitive polynomial $x^3+x+1$, we quickly see that $tr(1)=1$, $tr(g)=tr(g^2)=tr(g^4)=0$, $tr(g^3)=tr(g^5)=tr(g^6)=1$. Therefore
$$s_1=(-,+,+,-,+,-,-),$$
the sequence from above (by design). If we shift this sequence cyclically by $t$ positions, $0<t<7$, we see that we end up with the sequnce $s_{g^t}$. To explain a key property of $m$-sequence I conclude the example by explaining that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle c_1, c_{g^t}\rangle&=\sum_{j=0}^6 \chi_1(g^j)\chi_{g^t}(g^j)\\
&=\sum_{x\in GF(8)^*}\chi_1(x)\chi_{g^t}(x)\\
&=-1+\sum_{x\in GF(8)}\chi_1(x)\chi_{g^t}(x)\\
&=\begin{cases}
-1, &\text{if $0<t<7$}\\
7, &\text{if $t=0$.}\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
All due to the orthogonality of characters. What this means is that an $m$-sequence has perfect cross-correlation with its cyclic shifts. The inner product has an odd number of terms $\pm1$, so a sum of absolute value $1$ is the best we can hope.
A few concluding remarks:

The set of possible values of weights of words for the small Kasami code can be proven rather quickly using nothing but character sums and the orthogonality relation.
To get the weight distribution of the small Kasami code, you need a little bit extra. For example Macwilliam identities.
What I think of as quadratic codes (basically subcodes of a version of the second order Reed-Muller code) can be gotten (at least their cyclic variants) by evaluating $e(f(x))$ at all the points $x\in F$ or $F^*$, and constraining the polynomial $f(x)$ to only contain terms of degrees of Hamming weight $\le 2$. From my "answer" to your other question you will find that the small Kasami code uses exponents $1$ (of Hamming weight $1$) and $q+1=2^n+1$ (of Hamming weight two). In such cases we end up evaluating quadratic forms in $n$ variables over $V=GF(2)^n$.


I could keep going, but then I would reproduce scores of pages from textbooks. It is better that you look at one (the Handbook, Lidl & Niederreiter, Macwilliams & Sloane, Golomb has also written a most painless book on linear shift register sequences with minimal algebra prerequisities IIRC).

Thanks for the effort. Do you have the soft copy of the book "The Handbook of Coding Theory"?

No. But I would expect university libraries to carry it. If not math, then electrical engineering or information theory. It is a bit pricy for acquisition into a personal library.

Given a primitive element in $GF(2^m)$ of multiplicative order $2^m-1$ you can construct a binary $m-$sequence via
$$
tr(\alpha^t),\quad t=1,2,\ldots,2^m-2.
$$
where $tr(z)=z+z^2+\cdots+z^{2^{m-1}}$ is the absolute trace from $GF(2^m)$ to $GF(2).$
From basic number theory, an element $\theta$ is also primitive if it is of the form $\theta=\alpha^k,$ provided $\gcd(k,2^m-1).$ So this yields another $m-$sequence. However we need to count primitive polynomials instead to get distinct $m-$sequences (this $m$ has nothing to do with the degree $m$) which is
$
\phi(2^m-1)/m.
$
Thus there are only 2 distinct m-sequences of length 7. Some of those sequences from the BCH code are actually quadratic not linear sequences.

Hi! I can't find the literature on quadratic not linear sequences. How to identify them? I need to study the set $\mathcal{H}$, is there a way to mathematically analyse the various properties of the  $\mathcal{H}$?
